# Is $f_n(x)=nxe^{-n{x^2}}$ pointwise convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

What can I use in order to see if the sequence of functions $$f_n(x)=nxe^{-n{x^2}},  x\in[0,1]$$ is pointwise convergent? I'm not asking for full answer, just hints and helpful resources.

Comment: To my surprise, a google search returned 5 300 000 results for punctual convergence, and only 553 000 for pointwise convergence.

Comment: Do any native speakers use the expression "punctual convergence"?

Comment: Sorry, English is not my first language

Comment: I assume "punctual convergence" is from a French mathematician who doesn't know much english.

Answer (score 2):

You must treat two cases:

- Case $x=0$,
- Case $x\neq 0$ but $x$ is fixed point,

so you find that $(f_n)$ is pointwise convergent  to the zero function.